# iOS thread safe getter deadlocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I've create a singleton CarQueueClass with a `car` property which should be thread-safe. I've overridden the getter and setter for this property. When I try to get `self.car` within this class or access this property from the `sharedInstance`, it looks like it deadlocks. How can I return a Car in the getter without dispatch_sync deadlocking?

```
@interface CarQueueClass ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) Car * car;
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t carQueue;

@end

@implementation CarQueueClass

@synthesize 
car = _car

(id)init {
    if ([super init]) {
         self.carQueue = dispatch_queue_create("appName.SerialQueue", NULL);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setCar:(Car *)sampleCar
{
    dispatch_async(self.carQueue, ^{
        _car = sampleCar;
    });
}

- (Car *)car
{
    __block Car * tempCar;
    dispatch_sync(self.carQueue, ^{
        tempCar = _car;
    });
    return tempCar;
}
```

Comment: if you set a value on a queue, use a completion block.

Comment: Are you calling the getter when you are already on the `carQueue`? Doing a `dispatch_sync` to the current queue with deadlock on serial queues

Comment: Why not simply make the `car` property `atomic` and then get rid of your custom getter and setter. Or do you have other code in the class that you also need to make thread safe with the `_car` ivar? Clarify exactly what you mean by making the property thread-safe.

Comment: @dan I have a different method that calls dispatch_sync to check a field of `car`, and that method calls the getter for `car`. I guess I have to use a concurrent queue or do something else.

Comment: @rmaddy I'll look into making `car` atomic. I'm not very familiar with it. This singleton is likely accessed by several threads and sharing the `car` information. By thread-safe, I mean I want to avoid race conditions with reads and writes.

Comment: You should probably use a concurrent queue anyway and use `dispatch_barrier_async` in your setter.  There isn't really any point preventing multiple reads at the same time.

Comment: FWIW, if `Car` is mutable object, having synchronized accessor methods (much less making it atomic) does not ensure thread safety. See [Be Aware of Threats to Code Correctness](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW8). And I agree with Dan, that you should consider reader-writer pattern (concurrent queue and async barrier for writes).